# pandas apply with assignment on large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a very long dataframe `dfWeather` with the column `TEMP`. Because of its size, I want to keep only relevant information. Concretely, keep only entries, where the temperature changed by more than 1 since the last entry I kept. I want to use `dfWeather.apply`, since it seems to iterate much faster (10x) over the rows than a `for`-loop over `dfWeather.iloc`. I tried the following.

```
dfTempReduced = pd.DataFrame(columns = dfWeather.columns)    
dfTempReduced.append(dfWeather.iloc[0])    
dfWeather.apply(lambda x: dfTempReduced = dfTempReduced.append(x) if np.abs(TempReduced[-1].TEMP - x.TEMP) >= 1 else None, axis = 1)
```

unfortunately I get the error

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Is there a fast way to get that desired result? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is some example data

```
dfWeather[200:220].TEMP
Out[208]: 
200    12.28
201    12.31
202    12.28
203    12.28
204    12.24
205    12.21
206    12.17
207    11.93
208    11.83
209    11.76
210    11.66
211    11.55
212    11.48
213    11.43
214    11.37
215    11.33
216    11.36
217    11.33
218    11.29
219    11.27
```

The desired result would yield only the first and the last entry, since the absolute difference is larger than 1. The first entry is always included.

Comment: there are much faster ways to do this.  Can you post a small sample (~20 rows) of your data and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to call this recursive (so you have `[1, 2, 3]` and you want to keep `[1, 3]` because `2` is only 1 degree larger than `1` but `3` is more than 1 degree larger than `1`, but not than `2`) than you can simply use `diff`.

However, this doesn't work if the values stay longer below the 1°C threshold. To overcome this limitation, you could round the values (to whatever precision but 1°C suggests that to zero-precision would be a good idea;) )

Let us create an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['TEMP'] = np.random.rand(100) * 2
```

so now if you are OK with using `diff` it can be done very efficiently just by:

```py
# either slice
lg = df['TEMP'].apply(round).diff().abs() > 1
df = df[lg]

# or drop
lg = df['TEMP'].apply(round).diff().abs()  < 1
df.drop(index=lg.index, inplace=True)
```

You even have two options to to the reduction. I guess that `drop` take a minimal twink longer but  is more memory efficient than the slicing way.

Comment: Uunfortunately, this only looks at entries next to each other. If the jump takes longer than one step, it will not keep the sample.  E.g. if we start at 10 degrees, i want to keep the next sample that is over 11 or under 9. The amount of steps inbetween can be arbitrary.

Comment: fair enough. I'vd added a little tweak by rounding the numbers first and than reducing them. You can also `floor` or `ceil` or simply cast them to `int` in order to better control the behavior, where the "dropping border" is located